# How to validate a Bootstrap 3 angularJS form?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with some input type text, input type number, checkbox, radio, a select option and a submit button.
I want to validate each input. If a required input is not filled, I want to display a message.

Here's what happened : 
For my first input, the message appears when I did not select a radio and even when I select.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    I am : <br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="sex" name="sex" id="sex" value="femme"> <strong>Woman</strong>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="sex" name="sex" id="sex" value="homme"> <strong>Man</strong>
    </label>

    <div ng-show="form.sex.$error.required">
        <p class="help-block">
            Sex is required
        </p>                        
    </div>
</div>
```

I miss something it the same for others inputs. I don't see what I am missing ?

Second, I want to disable the submit button when there is an error on a input. This does not work. Here is my code :

```
<button ng-click="sendMessage();" class="btn btn-success pull-center" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" type="submit">Let me know</button>
```

You can see the complete code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yhS7vw9JEjWbq1uaQVun?p=preview).
Thanks for helping

Comment: The link to the plunker is missing

Comment: sorry i have updated the content with the real link

Comment: Try [Angular-Validator](https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfUE3uEjklJ2pow46Gs8?p=preview

```
<button ng-click="sendMessage();" class="btn btn-success pull-center" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" type="submit">Let me know</button>
```

1. use name attribute for all the fields you want to validate.
2. access error variables using form name. In you case its is "myForm".
3. You can disable form using the expressions:

   - myForm.$invalid
   - !myForm.$valid
4. name of your application is not correct in ng-app you have mentioned "myapp" and in script file it is "owmuchApp". I have used "owmuchApp" at both the places

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question. Do you know what to do if i want to add in validation the wish. I want to validate the form ( submit button) when the user check sport, travel or both ?

Comment: @Pracede Thank you so much. You may need an object array to put the selected values and a function to verify if that object array has any value or not. You can follow up this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632933/angularjs-group-check-box-validation

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your plunker add an error. You where using

```
ng-app="myApp"
```

instead of

```
ng-app="owmuchApp".
```

Your validation worked pretty well. I just added the "required" directive to both radio button and... it worked !

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vw8aglks9VU0kqf6pRBK?p=preview) working

Answer (score 2):

You had 2 problems, first the name of your application module was wrong,
("owmuchApp" in the `script.js` and "myApp" in the `index.html`) so the application wasn't even loading.

You need set the ng-required field of the radio buttons group this way:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="sex" ng-required="!sex" name="sex" id="sex" value="femme"> Woman
<input type="radio" ng-model="sex" ng-required="!sex" name="sex" id="sex" value="homme"> Man
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2FIUti?p=preview) is the working solution

**Update**

I forget to mention that i added a new condition on the show message:

```
<div ng-show="form.sex.$dirty && form.sex.$invalid">
  <p ng-show="form.sex.$error.required" class="help-block">
    Sex is required
  </p>
</div>
```

Will be shown only when the user tries to submit the form, otherwise the message was been shown soon as the form was rendered.

Comment: Ok i correct myApp in script.js. But i tried your plunker and when sex is not select the message does not appear. Did you provide the correct plunker ?

Comment: Is correct, i just update the answer, i forget to mention that i set the message to be shown when the form is submitted, otherwise the error message was always showed