# required checkbox group

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, required

I'm trying to validate a **group of checkboxes** where at least **one is required**. This is the HTML of my checkboxes:

```
<fieldset class="requiredcheckboxgroup">
    <legend>How did you come into contact with VK?*</legend>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.relations" group-required required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="relations" id="app-contact-relations" />relations<br>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.employees" group-required required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="employees" id="app-contact-employees" contact-employees />employees<br>
        <input ng-model="application.contact.employeesWho" type="text" placeholder="Who?" name="appcontact-employeeswho" id="app-contact-employees-who" disabled />
    <input ng-model="application.contact.jobad" group-required required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="jobad" id="app-contact-jobad" />jobad<br>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.website" group-required required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="website" id="app-contact-website" />website<br>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.other" group-required required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="other" id="app-contact-other" />other<br>
</fieldset>
```

As you can see all of my checkboxes have the *required attribute* and the *group-required attribute*. I have a directive like this:

```
angular.module('dxs-vkgroupApp').directive('groupRequired', group_required);

function group_required() {
    return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var requiredCheckboxes = jQuery('.requiredcheckboxgroup :checkbox[required]');

            requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){
                if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
                    requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
                }

                else {
                    requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that they **all have to be selected** before the form is valid... . The required attribute is correctly removed when one is selected but when I try to submit the form he still isn't valid.

How could I fix this? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Try to use ng-required directive and remove another required attribute on your form

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJs group check box validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632933/angularjs-group-check-box-validation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try creating a function that determines if any checkbox has been selected:

```
 angular('module').controller('MyController', function(){
    this.application = { contact: {} };

    this.noneSelected = function () {
      return !(application.contact.relations || application.contact.employees) /* ... */; 
    }
}
```

And then on your html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
<fieldset class="requiredcheckboxgroup">
    <legend>How did you come into contact with VK?*</legend>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.application.contact.relations" ng-required="ctrl.noneSelected()" type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="relations" id="app-contact-relations" />relations<br>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.application.contact.employees" ng-required="ctrl.noneSelected()" type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="employees" id="app-contact-employees" contact-employees />employees<br>
        <!-- .... -->
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: What about the directive you're referring to (contact-employees)? Should I use that also?

Comment: I copied it from your code, don't know what that directive does

Comment: that would be in your controller

Answer (score 0):

The directive should bind the change event. This is how it should be

```
<fieldset class="requiredcheckboxgroup">
    <legend>How did you come into contact with VK?*</legend>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.relations" ng-required="selected" group-required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="relations" id="app-contact-relations" />relations
    <br>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.employees" ng-required="selected" group-required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="employees" id="app-contact-employees" contact-employees />employees
    <br>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.employeesWho" type="text" placeholder="Who?" name="appcontact-employeeswho" id="app-contact-employees-who" disabled />
    <input ng-model="application.contact.jobad" ng-required="selected" group-required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="jobad" id="app-contact-jobad" />jobad
    <br>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.website" ng-required="selected" group-required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="website" id="app-contact-website" />website
    <br>
    <input ng-model="application.contact.other" ng-required="selected" group-required type="checkbox" name="appcontact" value="other" id="app-contact-other" />other
    <br>
</fieldset>
```

The directive should be

```
var app = angular.module('dxs-vkgroupApp', []);

app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.selected = true;

    }]);

    app.directive('groupRequired', group_required);

    function group_required() {
        return  {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {                    
                element.bind("change", function(){
                    var requiredCheckboxes = jQuery('.requiredcheckboxgroup input:checked').length;                        
                    if(requiredCheckboxes > 0)
                        scope.selected = false;
                    else
                        scope.selected = true;
                    scope.$apply();
                })
            }
        };
    }
```