# how to validate checkbox(mandatory) using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

This page lists stores with checkboxes. I need to put required field for checkbox,  if nothing is selected in that checkbox I need to put error message this field mandatory and nothing is selected submit button should disabled if user selected any one in that store list mandatory message should disappear and submit button should be enable.i have already done but when i checked 3 store then only message  disappear and submit button enabled.
Expectation:when user checked anyone listed checkbox message should disappear and submit button should enable.if nothing is checked in that checkbox message apper and submit button should be disbled.

```js
function Test1Controller($scope) {

    var serverData = ["Store1", "Store2", "Store3"];
    $scope.items = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
        var modal = {
            name: serverData[i],
            selected: false
        };
        $scope.items.push(modal);
    }

    $scope.check = function() {
        var checkedItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
                checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
            }
        }
        console.log(checkedItems);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <form name="projectForm">
        <div ng-controller="Test1Controller">
            <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" required="" /> {{item.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.booktime.$error">
                <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">* Mandatory</div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="projectForm.$invalid" ng-click="check()" />
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Same as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19633860/624590 (Use a checkbox group, and a validation function to check that something/anything is selected)

Comment: sorry can u help me i made same thing but it's not working for me

Comment: my Expectation if checkbox are not checked submit button should be disable.if any one selected then only user can submit

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked a few things in your code and got it to work.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<form name="projectForm">
    <div ng-controller="Test1Controller">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="itemsChecked()" required="" /> {{item.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.booktime.$error">
            <div class="form-error" ng-message="required" ng-show="!itemChecked">* Mandatory</div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="!itemChecked" ng-click="check()" />
    </div>
</form>
```

In the Javascript, you were not creating a controller properly. You should first create a module and then attach the controller to the module as shown below.

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("Test1Controller", function($scope) {
var serverData = ["Store1", "Store2", "Store3"];
$scope.items = [];

$scope.itemChecked = false;

for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
    var modal = {
        name: serverData[i],
        selected: false
    };
    $scope.items.push(modal);
}

$scope.itemsChecked = function() {
    $scope.itemChecked = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++)
    {
        if($scope.items[i].selected)
        {
            $scope.itemChecked = true;
        }
    }
}

$scope.check = function() {
    var checkedItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.items[i].selected) {
            checkedItems.push($scope.items[i].name);
        }
    }
    console.log(checkedItems);
}
});
```

Comment: Then you must be taking something wrong... here is a js fiddle showing it working. https://jsfiddle.net/bq5c1txd/