# Checkbox at least one click validation before submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, checkbox

I am currently checking the user input form before submit. i need to check if user click one of this checkbox before submitting the form.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.scope.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
   <label for="scope" >Scope</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.admin" name="scope[]" value="admin"> Admin <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.app" name="scope[]" value="app" > App <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.scope.redemption" name="scope[]" value="redemption" > Redemption <br>
   <br>
</div>
```

It works perfectly with radio button and input text when i set the input type  required. but it doesn't apply to checkbox. Anyone can help me?

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';" ng-hide="hideField">
 <label class="control-label" for="confirmpassword">Re-enter Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" ng-model="user.confirmpassword" required ng-minlength="5">
  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" ng-class="addUser.confirmpassword.$valid ? 'glyphicon-ok' : 'glyphicon-remove';"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="addUser.status.$valid ? 'has-success' : 'has-error';">
 <label for="status">Status</label><br>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="user.status" name="status" value="1" required> Active
  <input type="radio" ng-model="user.status" name="status" value="0" required> Inactive<br>
</div>
```

Comment: In submit button check the condition if any of the checkboxes ng-model is checked or not,,,,,

Comment: could u please give me an example? @MohaiminMoin

Comment: Well may be it is much easier to use ng-required as like  ng-required="user.scope.admin || user.scope.app || user.scope.redemption" in each of your checkbox.

Comment: its still not working that way @MohaiminMoin

Comment: Then suggest to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632933/angularjs-group-check-box-validation