# Make checkboxes required AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have a form where users have to answer questions through checkboxes. There are quite  few checkboxes and I'm using AngularJS in the form to validate it. A basic validation is that all the required fields are filled.

Below is my example code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skills"> IT
<input type="checkbox" name="skills"> Design
<input type="checkbox" name="skills"> Photoshop
<input type="checkbox" name="skills"> Writing
```

Now I want the checkboxes to be required so from the "skills" checkboxes the user atleast **checks 1 box**.

I've tried putting the `required` tag but it didn't seem to work.

Im using AngularJS to validate my form like so

```
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
```

Any idea how I can fix this? If you can working fiddle that would great.

Comment: It depends on your ng-model. If you are filling all the values into an array then you can do `myArray.length`

Comment: @nivas as more then 1 item can be checked I use a JavaScript function to loop through all the checkboxes and `push` all the "checked" boxes into an array. And send that array to my server. So didn't use the ng-model.

Comment: then you can check array length right

Comment: @nivas true. I can check array length but the array is only populated when I submit the form because thats when the functions loops through the checkboxes. Without "submitting" the form the array will always be empty even though the user has checked multiple boxes.

Comment: use ng-change event of checkbox and call a function in that that push element when user checks the checkbox and pop when user untick the checkbox so on form submission check the length of array if its empty then show him popup or alert message.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19633860/3153169)

Comment: @Skywalker did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate using ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"

```js
  var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

        app.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.choices = [{"name":"IT"},{"name":"Design"},{"name":"Technology"}];
            $scope.checkBoxArray = [];
            $scope.validate = function (value) {
                if ($scope.checkBoxArray.indexOf(value) == -1){
                    $scope.checkBoxArray.push(value);
                }
                else {
                    $scope.checkBoxArray.splice($scope.checkBoxArray.indexOf(value), 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myModule">
  <body ng-controller="myController">
<ng-form name="myForm">
    <span  ng-repeat="choice in choices">
        <input type="checkbox" name="skills" ng-required="checkBoxArray.length==0" ng-model="choice.checked" ng-change="validate(choice.name)">
        {{choice.name}}
    </span>
</ng-form>
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form name="checkBoxForm">
       <input type="checkbox" name="skills" ng-model="IT">IT
       <input type="checkbox" name="skills" ng-model="Design">Design
       <input type="checkbox" name="skills" ng-model="Photoshop">Photoshop
       <input type="checkbox" name="skills" ng-model="Writing">Writing

    <button ng-disabled="!IT&&!Design&&!Photoshop&&!Writing">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a array to do this:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {

$scope.collection=[{
                  "Name": "IT"},
              {
                  "Name": "Design"},
              {
                  "Name": "Photoshop"},
              {
                  "Name": "Writing"}];

$scope.disableButton = true;

$scope.doTheThings = function (item)
  {
    if (item.checked) 
      $scope.disableButton = true;
    else 
      $scope.disableButton = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in collection">
  <input type="checkbox" name="skills" ng-model="item.checked" ng-click="doTheThings(item)"> {{item.Name}}
 </li>
</ul>
<button ng-disabled="disableButton"> Submit </button>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Some bugs are there in this answer. when you click more than one checkbox and uncheck a checkbox, then the submit button disables even if there are some checkboxes are already checked.