# Angular input type text or at least one check box validation

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to implement the following behavior. 
I have a form and I want to require filling at least one of the check boxes or text field.
I am trying to do this with the following code, but I don't know what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/AlexLavriv/mc8fj4f9/

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('App', []).controller("Ctrl", Ctrl); 
function Ctrl($scope) {

$scope.formData = {};

$scope.formData.selectedFruits = {};

$scope.fruits = [{'name':'Apple', 'id':1}, {'name':'Orange', 'id':2}, {'name':'Banana', 'id':3}, {'name':'Mango', 'id':4},];

$scope.someSelected = function (object) {
   console.log(object);
    for (var i in object)
    {
        if (object[i]){
        return true;
        }

    }


return false;
}

$scope.submitForm = function() {
    console.log($scope.formData.selectedFruits);
}
}


<div ng-controller="Ctrl" >
    <form class="Scroller-Container" name="multipleCheckbox" novalidate >
        <div ng-app>
          <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
              <div>
                What would you like?
                <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in fruits">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.selectedFruits[val.name]">
                      {{val.name}}
                </div>
                <p class="error" ng-show="submitted && multipleCheckbox.$error.required">Select check box or input text</p>
               </div>
               <pre>{{formData.selectedFruits}}</pre>
 <input type="text"  ng-required="!someSelected(formData.selectedFruits)" />
               <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" />
            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-model` missing for **text field**

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't use ng-required with a function</strike>

You can find another solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/mc8fj4f9/2/

```
var app = angular.module('App', []).controller("Ctrl", Ctrl); 
function Ctrl($scope) {

 $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.formData.selectedFruits = {};

    $scope.fruits = [{'name':'Apple', 'id':1}, {'name':'Orange', 'id':2}, {'name':'Banana', 'id':3}, {'name':'Mango', 'id':4},];

    $scope.submited=false;

    $scope.someSelected = function (object) {
       console.log(object);
        for (var i in object)
        {
            if (object[i]){
              $scope.checkboxSelected =true;
              return true;
            }

        }

      $scope.checkboxSelected =false;
      return false;
    }

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        console.log("submit "+ $scope.formData.selectedFruits);
        $scope.submitted=true;
        $scope.someSelected($scope.formData.selectedFruits);     

    }
}



<div ng-controller="Ctrl" >
        <form class="Scroller-Container" name="multipleCheckbox" novalidate>
            <div ng-app>
              <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
                  <div>
                    What would you like?
                    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in fruits">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.selectedFruits[val.name]" ng-required = "!inputVal">
                          {{val.name}}
                    </div>
                    <p class="error" ng-show="submitted && !checkboxSelected && !inputVal">Select check box or input text</p>
                   </div>
                   <pre>{{formData.selectedFruits}}</pre>
     <input type="text"  ng-required="!checkboxSelected" ng-model="inputVal"/>
                   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitForm()" />
                </div>
              </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why can't I use a function in ng-required directive? It seems like very common practice - for example here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632933/angularjs-group-check-box-validation and now my code is working. It seems that the missing ng-model was the problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, you are right with the ng-required directive, hope that my solution is still helpful to show you a different approach :). As you, I am still learning AngularJS.